# How to call java class which has WebDriver elements in Robot Framework?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
public void EnterLoginDetails(String userName, String password) throws Exception {

 System.out.println("User name, " + userName + "!");
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
 System.out.println("User name, " + userName + "!");
 element.click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='username']")).sendKeys(userName);

 Thread.sleep(1000);
 System.out.println("Password, " + password + "!");
 driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
 Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I want to validate this method in robot framework. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify, what is your question? How to run the Java code from RobotFramework? Or, how to replicate it _in_ RobotFramework? Or something different?

Comment: I want to run this java code in Robot Framework? How to import java class